# Android BottomSheet wrong template after download from GoolgePlay

Tags: android, google-play, bottom-sheet

in my application I am using the BottomSheet component. This is a `GridLayout` with 3x2 buttons.

After loading into GooglePlay on some phones, the bottom sheet template becomes one empty button.
If I use Android Studio and download my application to a problem phone, it works correctly.

> Where could the problem be? Or may be someone saw this behavior

[image]

bottom_sheet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
    style="@style/BottomSheetDialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/backColor"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
app:columnCount="3"
app:rowCount="2">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/crossReadyMenu"
    style="@style/LightButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_ready_24px"
    android:text="@string/cross_ready"
    app:layout_column="2"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1" />
<!-- and 5 other buttons-->
</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

parent.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/patternDetailLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".pattern.PatternDetailActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<include
    layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity

```
    private lateinit var bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
...
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomMenu)
    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
```

Comment: are you sure you constrained your button to work on all screen sizes ?

Comment: Button width and height is wrap_content. I can see only the first button without text and icon

Comment: can you show your layout and how you re constraining views /